# Copy columns and paste values (not formulas)

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

AlexP provided the following code to a question about copying columns. It works great for me except that in ws1, the columns have equations that get copied over to ws2. I just want to copy over the values, not the equations.

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
    Dim header As Range, headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("ws1").Range("A1:Z1")

    For Each header In headers
        If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
            Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ws2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
    Dim headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("ws2").Range("A1:Z1")
    GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Check this out:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/49124-visual-basic-applications-copy-paste-cell-value-only-not-formula.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split this line:

```
Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ws2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
```

and use the `.PasteSpecial()` method instead

---

e.g.

```
Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy
Worksheets("ws2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value)).PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```